# Shutdown Flask server after response

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've been reading a lot around different ways to shutdown a Flask app but I don't get it how I could implement something for my use case.

I wrote and am testing a simple Flask app which takes a POST request to create some resources within Google Cloud. This Flask app is deployed into a container and is running on Cloud Run.

My question is, I want to shutdown the app right after a 200 response or would there be a way to handle one request per Cloud Run instance?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
   #some validation on the request.json
   try:
      kick_off_terraform()
      return ("Success", 200)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Comment: This seems to be a rather exotic use-case for a web application. Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: Hi Klaus, I agree with you but I have a particular use case where I have to handle one unique request per instance (no concurrent requests) and after doing a little more research now looks like I found what I need on GCP side to set the number of concurrency per instance. I will go ahead and mark this post as closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found out I can control the concurrency on the GCP side, and that way I can allow only one request per instance on Cloud Run.

```
gcloud run deploy $SERVICE_NAME 
          --image gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$SERVICE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
          --region=us-east1 
          --platform managed 
          --concurrency=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly hacks like `--concurrency=1` or `--max-instances=1` are not great because shutting down the server after a request may cause the request to fail.  (When I did that in the past, requests failed.)

Based on your question I am guessing you might not have fully grasped Cloud Run runtime behavior. Please note that:

1. You don't need to "shut down" a container on Cloud Run. It automatically suspends once all requests finish, and you are not even charged for the idle time that occurs outside of a request.
2. Operations like `kick_off_terraform()` can't happen in the background (they have to finish before you return the response), because Cloud Run currently doesn't allocate CPU in the background.

What you need is something like "run to completion containers" and you may need to wait a bit for that to be supported by Cloud Run.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, I appreciate your input. I think I miss explained my problem in the original post. The shutdown idea was a 'hacky' way to make sure cloud run would suspend the container and not let any other requests hit the same running container. In my use case, kick_off_terraform() function will run and only once all the resources have been created (or not) I return a response back and handle it from there. So before I set the concurrency=1 what ended up happening was two requests hitting the same container which was causing conflicts in my terraform state file which is locally for in my use case

Comment: It's hard to run something exactly once in Cloud Run today. Combining --max-instances=1 and --concurrency=1 will get you close, but you may still get a second instance starting up in case Cloud Run needs to migrate things between machines or thinks something is unhealthy with your container.